# Spring is not filling other variables when one injected dependency requires a bean in the same class

Tags: java, spring

So, I have the following class:

```
@Configuration
public class BeansConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private Config config; //Only values of a config file
    
    @Autowired
    private JDAListener listener;
    
    @Autowired
    private PermissionProvider permissionProvider;
    @Autowired
    private LanguageProvider languageProvider;
    @Autowired
    private PrefixProvider prefixProvider;
    @Autowired
    private HelpProvider helpProvider;
    
    @Bean
    public ShardManager shardManager() throws LoginException, IllegalArgumentException {
        DefaultShardManagerBuilder builder = DefaultShardManagerBuilder.createDefault(this.config.getBotToken())
                .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
                .setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL)
                .setStatus(OnlineStatus.IDLE)
                .setShardsTotal(this.config.getTotalShards())
                .addEventListeners(Arrays.asList(this.listener));
        
        ShardManager manager = builder.build();
        this.commandFramework().setShardManager(manager);
        
        return manager;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CommandFramework commandFramework() {
        LogManager.getLogger().error("HelpProvider name: " + this.helpProvider.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        return new FrameworkBuilder()
                .addOwners(Arrays.stream(this.config.getOwnerIds()).filter(ownerId -> ownerId.matches("^(\\d)+$")).map(ownerId -> Long.parseLong(ownerId)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .setLogger(NightBot.logger())
                .allowBots(false)
                .allowDM(false)
                .allowMention(true)
                .allowRainbowColors(true)
                .withPrefixProvider(this.prefixProvider)
                .withLanguageProvider(this.languageProvider)
                .withPermissionProvider(this.permissionProvider)
                .withHelpProvider(this.helpProvider)
                .withCustomArgumentProcessor(new NamedArgumentProcessor())
                .registerClientLater()
                .build();
    }
}
```

When I try to use this class it fails because of a possible circular reference. I checked the code and found out that all is okay and there should be no circular reference. So I tried out and detected that when the Bean commandFramework is in creation, the injected variables are all null, because of the JDA Listener requiring the CommandFramework as dependency. When the command framework was created with the null values, all works, the Shard Manager can be created with the jda listener and all the other variables then available. So my question is, why does Spring not first inject the providers, then creates the CommandFramework bean, as it requires them, then injects the JDA Listener with the CommandFramework dependency and then at last creates the shard manager? Why is it required that all variables are created so that the bean can be created? Why does it not try to create that bean first before injecting JDAListener.

### The Stacktrace

As asked, here the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'beansConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'listener'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'JDAListener': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cf'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commandFramework' defined in class path resource [dev/teamnight/nightbot/BeansConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dev.teamnight.command.CommandFramework]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'beansConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'commandFramework' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at dev.teamnight.nightbot.NightBotApplication.main(NightBotApplication.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'JDAListener': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cf'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commandFramework' defined in class path resource [dev/teamnight/nightbot/BeansConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dev.teamnight.command.CommandFramework]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'beansConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'commandFramework' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commandFramework' defined in class path resource [dev/teamnight/nightbot/BeansConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dev.teamnight.command.CommandFramework]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'beansConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'commandFramework' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dev.teamnight.command.CommandFramework]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'beansConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'commandFramework' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at dev.teamnight.nightbot.BeansConfig.commandFramework(BeansConfig.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
        at dev.teamnight.nightbot.BeansConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fea6c58e.CGLIB$commandFramework$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at dev.teamnight.nightbot.BeansConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fea6c58e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3b1aec1a.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at dev.teamnight.nightbot.BeansConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fea6c58e.commandFramework(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 45 common frames omitted
```

The Stacktrace says that the helpProvider and that is caused because the `BeansConfig` class members weren't filled with the specificed providers. But the providers are independent from `CommandFramework` and `ShardManager`, so they should be injected.

Why does spring not do this in this order:

1. Try to inject all variables, JDAListener fails, but the providers are injected, JDAListener requires a bean commandFramework
2. Create the bean with the name commandFramework
3. Try again to create JDAListener, now it succeeds
4. Create the bean with name ShardManager

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who comes up with the same problem, here is my solution.

I randomly found some piece of code which I tried out and fixed my problem. I removed the `@Autowired private JDAListener listener` which required the `CommandFramework` bean and put it as method paramter for the `ShardManager`. Now the `BeansConfig` object can be created and the beans are also created successfully:

```java
@Configuration
public class BeansConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private Config config;
    
    @Autowired
    private PermissionProvider permissionProvider;
    @Autowired
    private LanguageProvider languageProvider;
    @Autowired
    private PrefixProvider prefixProvider;
    @Autowired
    private HelpProvider helpProvider;
    
    @Bean
    public ShardManager shardManager(JDAListener listener) throws LoginException, IllegalArgumentException {
        DefaultShardManagerBuilder builder = DefaultShardManagerBuilder.createDefault(this.config.getBotToken())
                .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
                .setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL)
                .setStatus(OnlineStatus.IDLE)
                .setShardsTotal(this.config.getTotalShards())
                .addEventListeners(Arrays.asList(listener));
        
        ShardManager manager = builder.build();
        this.commandFramework().setShardManager(manager);
        
        return manager;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CommandFramework commandFramework() {
        LogManager.getLogger().error("HelpProvider name: " + this.helpProvider.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        return new FrameworkBuilder()
                .addOwners(Arrays.stream(this.config.getOwnerIds()).filter(ownerId -> ownerId.matches("^(\\d)+$")).map(ownerId -> Long.parseLong(ownerId)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .setLogger(NightBot.logger())
                .allowBots(false)
                .allowDM(false)
                .allowMention(true)
                .allowRainbowColors(true)
                .withPrefixProvider(this.prefixProvider)
                .withLanguageProvider(this.languageProvider)
                .withPermissionProvider(this.permissionProvider)
                .withHelpProvider(this.helpProvider)
                .withCustomArgumentProcessor(new NamedArgumentProcessor())
                .registerClientLater()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, it's preferable to inject a dependency as a method parameter than autowired as an instance variable, since the former minimizes the scope of the dependency, and makes it clearer who is using it.